# Emgu.DrawContours() can not fill region

Tags: c#, opencv, contour, emgucv

I want to fill regions by setting  thickness  to -1.Result is Unbelievable：the second contour is filled ,but the first is not filled.

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOHo8.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zEeC.png)

```
var result= new Image<Bgr, byte>(source.Width, source.Height);
result.SetValue(new Bgr(255,255,255));

VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours =new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
var temp = source.Canny(128, 255);
CvInvoke.FindContours(temp , contours,null, RetrType.External,ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

CvInvoke.DrawContours(result, contours, 1, new MCvScalar(0,255,0),-1);
CvInvoke.DrawContours(result, contours, 0, new MCvScalar(0,255, 0), -1);

result =result.GetSubRect(getMaxRectangle(contours))
```

I tried to use different `LineType` but failed, especially `LineType.Filled` cause a error :`OpenCV: connectivity == 8 || connectivity == 4`. I want to know why it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just write the code in python, if it will help you:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # convert to gray
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # inverse thresholding
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # find contours
imContoured = cv2.drawContours(im.copy(), contours, 0, (0,0,255), -1) # fill it blue (in cv it will be red)
imContoured = cv2.drawContours(imContoured, contours, 1, (0,255,0), -1) # fill it green
```

And here is the result:

[image: Result]

So basically no need to do Canny edge detection, your image is good to go with some threshold (remember to use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`)

Okay so I guess maybe for you, this will be something like this:

```
Mat gray = new Mat();
CvInvoke.CvtColor(source, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
// Inverse thresholding
Mat threshold = new Mat();
CvInvoke.Threshold(gray, threshold, 250, 255, ThresholdType.BinaryInv);
// Find contours
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
CvInvoke.FindContours(threshold, contours, null, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.None);
```

The drawing would not change anything, it is correct. I guess with canny detection something went wrong, can't say what exactly, but maybe the contour was broken or something. To make sure, can you please show us how your canny edges looked like?

Comment: Oh,thank you for your suggestions.I find the canny edges incorrest.```var result = new Image<Bgr, byte>(source.Width, source.Height);
result.SetValue(new Bgr(255, 255, 255));
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
var canny = source.Canny(128, 255);
canny.Save("canny.png");```

Comment: Can you show us the image?

Comment: The question is that there is a short line in canny.png in (400,100).      i can not show canny.png,because the website send a notification -- As soon as you earn 10 reputation on the site, you'll be able to embed.

Comment: that's a bummer, well I hope I helped solve your question. If I did, please remember to close the question. Would appreciate it!

Comment: Very good! I have change my Profile image to canny.png.

Comment: Ah I see your problem, your Canny edge detection was not able to identify the thin square like shape because of it being thin. It detected it as one line and therefore the contour _is the line_. Hence filling it you will only fill the borders. Try to use canny with a smaller width. Here is a nice tutorial: https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/05/12/opencv-edge-detection-cv2-canny/.